# How to insert value to {% url tag %} from js script inside django template

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet

I'm using leaflet JS in Django template. I want to show markers on map where latitude and longitude is taken from a queryset. I figured out that I can send queryset by views and then using Django template language use it inside  to set lat i lon to particular marker. I would like to have an image in popup of marker and here my problem comes. I know that I can't use JS because it's client side vs Django template is server side but how to solve case where you want to dynamically create markers and popup with image which is in database.
Should I use AJAX to do that?

my views:

```
class MapView(ListView):
    template_name = 'map.html'
    model = Post
    queryset = serialize('json', Post.objects.all(), fields = ['lat','lon', 'image'])
```

and template where below for loop is marker1 where popup is hard-coded and works ok:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([49.175573,20.072700], 11);
    
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var post_base = {{object_list|safe}}
    
    for (let index = 0; index < post_base.length; index++) {
        console.log(post_base[index]['fields']['lat']);

        var image_path = post_base[index]['fields']['images']
        marker = new L.marker([post_base[index]["fields"]["lat"],post_base[index]["fields"]["lon"]]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup("<img style=10%; src={% static 'images/????????????????????????'%}/>");
    }

marker1 = new L.marker([49.295236, 20.413089],{opacity:0.5}).addTo(map)
    .bindPopup("<img src={% static 'images/lomnica_image.jpeg' %}/>");

</script>
```

Could anybody explain what is proper way to solve it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are absolutely correct you can't execute your js code on server side without builder or something like webpack, parcel etc.

So if you decide to render marker runtime with client side your probably need to try [django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) that provide a lot of tools for creating REST API like serializers and viewsets.

But ofcourse your still can use native Django to make data serialization is easy using [Django serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/)

Also you can use [this repository](https://bitbucket.org/marbleperformer/django20190130/src/master/) as example for start.

Comment: I have thought about using Vue to that and only to that page. Rest of it I would like to have in regular django. Is it not overkill to implement Vue just to render a popup in marker?

Comment: It's likely depends of project stack and to be honest I don't see anything wrong with using Vue.js only for that purpose but if you want to use Vue.js or another js framework you need first to think about using task runner or builder such as webpack or gulp.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have dug a little and find that I can use fetch in JS to get image path from database. Still don't know exactly how :) but it'm closer than yesterday.